# Correct HTML Syntax - bold inside list tag or list inside bold tag

Tags: html

I have a simple question to ask. Since I can't find any online article, posting my question here to get your views.

Which of the below syntax is correct? `b` inside `li` or `li` inside `b`. Although both does the job of making the font weight bold, I would love to know if one syntax is correct and the other one is not.

```html
<ul>
  <li><b>1</b></li>
  <li><b>2</b></li>
  <li><b>3</b></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <b><li>1</li></b>
  <b><li>2</li></b>
  <b><li>3</li></b>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would personally prefer the first version because the `b` tag is about styling your text, and the `li` is for structuring it (even though it adds some style, its main purpose is structuring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is easily tested by passing the HTML through [a validator](https://validator.nu/) or looking at [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

A `b` element may not be a child of a `ul` element, so the latter is invalid.

The former is allowed.

---

That said, presentation is a job for CSS, not HTML, so you should be applying your bold face from your stylesheet.

```css
li {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @Seblor. Sure. Done